# How to deal with inconsistent font sizes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

Attached is a screen capture of a map I'm trying to do. According to Adobe Illustrator both "COSTERO" are the same size and font. I tried the eye dropper to get them the same. Tried copying one and pasting into the other.

What's causing this discrepancy? How can I correct it?

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

[image]

Edit: As per Danielillo's suggestion I compared text panels. Screen capture below. Neither was subscript or superscript. Character style in both cases is Normal Character Style.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid all anyone can do is *guess* without examining the file.  One may have transform effects on it.

Comment: @Scott Transform effects?

Comment: @HopDavid the balloon next to object or layer

Answer (score 4):

From the **Text Panel**, check if all the fields are equal.

The small word could be a **Superscript** or **Subscript**

[image: text panel]

From the **Text Style Panel**, check there's not any style applied.

[image: text style]

Comment: Yes, or it could be the small caps setting to the left of the Superscript icon.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. Gave you an upvote. I'll admit to super scripting and forgetting about it. However none of these seem to be the root of my present conundrum. I am having to typeset road names from scratch rather using what I had typeset earlier. Added a screen capture of my text panels to the question.